# Django crispy-forms cannot find CSS

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am using Django and Crispy Forms. I can get the form to render correctly, but no CSS formatting appears. What do I need to do?

I have added

```
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap'
```

to my `settings.py` file.

The html file is as simple as it gets:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
   {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

What else is necessary to make it work? I understand that since the bootstrap files come bundled with crispy_forms, I don't need to copy and reference them specifically in my project's CSS path. Is this correct?

Comment: In the browser console do you see any errors about the css files which are failed to load? If yes then you need to colllect the static files at one place.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if your django instance can't find the `static` files for crispy forms. If you are running the development server, have you included `'crispy_forms'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

If you're running a production server you'll probably need to ensure that your `STATIC_FILES` paths are correct and you've run `collectstatic` recently.

The authors have documented the installation process [here](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#installing-django-crispy-forms) - have you followed that completely?

Answer (score 1):

Its supposed to be `{{ form|crispy }}`, not `{{ crispy form }}`. You are putting the form through a filter (which is what `|` does in Django templates).
Also, you forgot the `{% csrf_token %}`.