# Django crispy forms not loading CSS

Tags: django, django-templates, django-crispy-forms

I saw this question on SO: [Django crispy-forms cannot find CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683614/django-crispy-forms-cannot-find-css), and followed all of the suggestions in the accepted answer, i.e.:

- 'crispy-forms' is listed under INSTALLED_APPS
- I'm not running a production server, so I'm not sure the collectstatic option applied (although I did run it)

Also: I am trying to use the bootstrap template pack, so I added CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap' into my settings.py file.

When I load the form created by the example from https://gist.github.com/maraujop/1838193, there is no CSS on the page.  Any advice?  Thanks!

**Edit:**
I think I'm still missing something.  I downloaded Bootstrap, unzipped it into a static dir inside my app, i.e.:

```
my_app/
    static/
        css/
        js/
        img/
```

I created a base.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my template, I have:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
   {% crispy form %}
{% endblock %}
```

When I try and load my page, the form loads (whew), but still no CSS.  When I look at the source of the page, I can see the following:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

but Django can't seem to find the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [include the css/js yourself](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#setting-media-files). So... [Download bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/), put the files in your static files directory, include a link to the bootstrap css/js files in your `base.html` template, then you will be able to see the proper formatting.

Comment: Would you please look at my edit above?  I tried to do what you suggested, but something still isn't quite right.  Thanks!

Comment: @user2406467 did you set the correct settings, [STATIC_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url) and [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs)? My guess is if you set those, you will be all set.

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/' and STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/Users/me/bootstrap',)

Comment: @user2406467 something is wrong then, it looks like `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is empty if your link looks like that when output. Do you have `"django.core.context_processors.static",` in your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS?

Comment: That seems to be the missing piece.  Once I added that, and reloaded, the CSS showed up.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `pip install crispy_bootstrap4` 4 or 5 based on your requirements.
Add it to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list and add these to the `settings.py` file:

```
CRISPY_ALLOWED_TEMPLATE_PACKS = "bootstrap4"
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"
```