# Unable to install Django package in a Docker container

Tags: django, docker, django-crispy-forms

I'm trying to install a simple Django package in a Docker container.

Here is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1 
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /app/ 
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
COPY . /app/
```

And here is my docker-compose:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /app/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app 
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - /Users/ruslaniv/Documents/Docker/djangoapp:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=XXX
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXX
      - POSTGRES_DB=djangoapp
volumes:
  djangoapp:
```

So, I start my container with

```
docker-compose up
```

then install a package and rebuild an image

```
docker-compose exec web pipenv install django-crispy-forms
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Then I add `'crispy_forms'` into local `settings.py` and register crispy forms tags in a local html file with `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` and then use them for the form with `{{ form|crispy }}`

But the form is not rendered properly.
Since the package itself and its usage are very simple I think there is a problem with installing the package in a container.

So the question is how to properly install a Django package in a Docker container and am I doing it properly?

Comment: Could you verify that after `docker-compose exec ...` and `docker-compose down` but before `docker-compose up -d --build` the `django-crispy-forms` is added to the Pipfile in your local file system? Also why do you need to add the package in the container? If you add it before building the container does it work?

Comment: @MichalKrejčí Yes, once I've installed `django-crispy-forms` inside the container and shut it down I can see `django-crispy-forms` entries in both local `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. In regard to the 2nd comment - I read somewhere that this was a *better* practice since native OS and Docker OS are different, if I install locally the dependency graph in `Pipfile.lock` will be *incorrect* when deployed inside the container.

Comment: @MichalKrejčí If i install `django-crispy-forms` inside the container and then, without rebuilding, try to add appropriate entries into the local `settings.py` and html files, the web server running inside the container crashes with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17454514/django-crispy-forms-not-loading-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question was about installing Django packages in a Docker container, the solution was much simpler.

The two facts I should have paid closer attention to:

1. After installing `django-crispy-forms` inside a container, I could see appropriate entries appearing in local `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` (hat tip to @MichalKrejčí)
2. After rebuilding the image and running it, Django server was **NOT** crashing with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crispy_forms'`

All that meant that the package was installed successfully and there was something else going on.

Which was the fact that I had to manually include Bootstrap4 CSS files for crispy-forms to render forms according to a Bootstrap4 template.

Answer (score 0):

first, you should stop your container

```
docker-compose down
```

second, activate your local environment
if using pipenv

```
pipenv shell
pipenv install django-crispy-forms
```

third, rebuild your container

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

and last, stop your container again and

```
docker-compose up -d
```